# I am trying to connect mongodb server with node

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I tried to connect my mongo cluster with my local server but this error keeps on showing up. I am following a tutorial and it seems to work fine for the tutor but this error comes for me. I have provided the error screenshot below.

[Error which comes up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P7sth.png)

The src has been provided

```js
const express = require('express');
const env = require('dotenv');
const app = express();
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

//routes
const userRoutes = require('./routes/user');

//constants
env.config();

//mongodb connect
//mongodb+srv://root:<password>@cluster0.9ylhh.mongodb.net/myFirstDatabase?retryWrites=true&w=majority
mongoose.connect(
    `mongodb+srv://${process.env.MONGO_DB_USER}:${process.env.MONGO_DB_PASSWORD}@cluster0.9ylhh.mongodb.net/${process.env.MONGO_DB_DATABASE}?retryWrites=true&w=majority`,
    {
        useNewUrlParser: true,
        useUnifiedTopology: true,
        useCreateIndex: true
    }
).then(() => {
    console.log('Database connected');
});

//middleware
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true}));
app.use(express.json());


app.listen(process.env.PORT, () => {
    console.log(`server is running on port ${process.env.PORT}`);
});
```

I also did create a .env file with the credentials details and stuff

Comment: What credentials are you using ? Did you create a specific user to access this specific cluster ? Also by default there is an IP blocking enabled ... for development just allow traffic from 0.0.0.0 .

Answer (score 0):

I tried to make a comment instead of an answer, but I don't have enough reputation.

If the error is authentication, maybe you have a problem with your credentials.

Does your username or password have any of these chars? `: / ? # [ ] @`
If they do, you'll have to URI encode them like so:

`${encodeURIComponent(process.env.MONGO_DB_USER)}`

`${encodeURIComponent(process.env.MONGO_DB_PASSWORD)}`

More info here: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/connection-string/#examples

BTW: You forgot the `env` part on your `${process.MONGO_DB_PASSWORD}`.